# Extra / when redirecting a default route

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I configured my `RouteInitializer` as following:

```dart
class AppRouteInitializer implements RouteInitializer {

  init(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
    router.root
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'root',
          path: '/lounge_client_demo/web/lounge_client_demo.html',
          mount: (Route route) => route
            ..addRoute(
                name: 'lobby',
                path: '#lobby',
                enter: view('views/LobbyView.html'))
            ..addRoute(
                name: 'chat',
                path: '#chat',
                enter: view('views/ChatView.html'))
            ..addRoute(
                name: 'default',
                defaultRoute: true,
                enter: (_) => router.go('lobby', {'param': ':param'}, startingFrom: route, replace: false))
      );
  }

}
```

The URL's to lobby and chat:

`http://127.0.0.1:3030/lounge_client_demo/web/lounge_client_demo.html#lobby`
`http://127.0.0.1:3030/lounge_client_demo/web/lounge_client_demo.html#chat`

are working as expected. But, when I submit an URL like:

`http://127.0.0.1:3030/lounge_client_demo/web/lounge_client_demo.html`

or

`http://127.0.0.1:3030/lounge_client_demo/web/lounge_client_demo.html#xxx`

the rule in the `defaultRoute` is producing the following wrong URL:

`http://127.0.0.1:3030/lounge_client_demo/web/lounge_client_demo/.html#lobby`

Am I assuming something wrong here or is it just a bug?

**UPDATE:** The logging shows that the dot in the URL is being escaped and might be wrongly transformed into the target URL.

```
2014-01-29 01:20:18.026: FINEST : route /lounge_client_demo/web/lounge_client_demo.html [Route: null]
2014-01-29 01:20:18.035: FINEST : _processNewRoute /lounge_client_demo/web/lounge_client_demo.html
2014-01-29 01:20:18.047: FINEST : route  [Route: root]
2014-01-29 01:20:18.055: FINEST : _processNewRoute 
2014-01-29 01:20:18.066: FINEST : go /lounge_client_demo/web/lounge_client_demo\.html#lobby
2014-01-29 01:20:18.075: FINEST : route #lobby [Route: root]
2014-01-29 01:20:18.087: FINEST : _processNewRoute #lobby
2014-01-29 01:20:18.099: FINEST : route  [Route: default]
2014-01-29 01:20:18.108: FINEST : route  [Route: lobby]
```

**UPDATE:** I have copied the `lounge_client_demo.html` into `test.file.with.dots.html` and get the following URL rewrite:

`http://127.0.0.1:3030/lounge_client_demo/web/test/.file/.with/.dots/.html#lobby`

The logging shows that every period is being "escaped" by a backslash:

```
2014-01-30 01:16:28.246: FINEST : go /lounge_client_demo/web/test\.file\.with\.dots\.html#lobby
```

**Possibly a problem with the period character in the route_hierarchical package?!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be including `#` in the route paths, so just `'lobby'`, not `'#lobby'` -- router is doing that for you. If you want to use the fragment (`#...`) for routing then you need to include the following in your module:

```
module.value(NgRoutingUsePushState, NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));
```

which  tells the router to use `window.location.hash` instead of `window.location.path` for routing, as well as to listen to `window.onHashChange` instead of `window.onPopState`.

That said, you can either do path matching or fragment matching, but not both. So, you'll also need to remove the 'root' route (for path `'/lounge_client_demo/web/lounge_client_demo.html'`). Once you switch to fragment matching path becomes irrelevant, only stuff after `#` is passed to the router.

Your route configuration should look something like this:

```dart
class AppRouteInitializer implements RouteInitializer {

  init(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
    router.root
        ..addRoute(
            name: 'lobby',
            path: 'lobby',
            enter: view('views/LobbyView.html'))
        ..addRoute(
            name: 'chat',
            path: 'chat',
            enter: view('views/ChatView.html'))
        ..addRoute(
            name: 'default',
            defaultRoute: true,
            enter: (_) => router.go('lobby', {'param': ':param'}));
  }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. Adding *NgRoutingUsePushState(false)* is making no view shown and the defaultRoute not kicking in. Removing the *#* is simply removing the # from the resulting URL. I tried both on Dart VM and V8. I recon you know the most about the *route_hierarchical* package, but I still find very suspicious that log entry from the go method ;-)

Comment: Ah, yes. You also need to remove the root route altogether. You don't need it.

Comment: I mean, you can either do path matching or fragment matching, but not both.